# How can the scanner reread the entire file after it has already executed hasNextLine once?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

What is the optimal way for the scanner to reread the contents of the file from the beginning? Since in the verticesSet function, I'm using while (scanner.hasNextLine()), which reads until there are no more values in the file because it has already read them all, when I call the edgesSet function, nothing happens because it tries to read values from the file, but the "cursor" is positioned at the very end.

I know it's possible to prevent this by reopening a new scanner and passing it to the edgesSet function, but is that the right way to do it? For example, if I have 10 other functions, I probably wouldn't want to create a new scanner each time. Is there a way to tell it to read from the beginning of the file?

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File fileName = new File("test.txt");
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileName );
            verticesSet(scanner);
            edgesSet(scanner);
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.err.println("file not found" + exception.getMessage());
        }
    }



public static void verticesSet(Scanner scanner) {
        Set<Integer> verticesSet = new HashSet<>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            verticesSet.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println(verticesSet);
    }

public static void edgesSet(Scanner scanner) {
        List<String> edges = new ArrayList<>();

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            edges.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("index" + i + " is" + edges.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just store them in memory if resources permit?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it. Or if you want to read the file only once, then you could save each line into a list/array and then pass the array to each of your methods.

Comment: @g00se Are you referring to those values from the file? Why don't I store them in memory? Without going into much detail here, I'll say that I can't; I have to read them from the file.

Comment: Why? There there are few if any processes in computing that demand reading a file twice. Compilers don’t. Why do you?

Comment: You simply read _only_ the edges in. Then, you write a method that calculates the  vertices based on the edges, which is trivially possible. _Then_, you run that `index i is ` for loop which has no business being in a method that parses some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do it is to create a new `Scanner`. The `Scanner` doesn't expose its internal construct for reading files and so there's no public way to seek back to the beginning. If for some reason you really don't want to do this you could *try* using the `ReadableByteChannel` constructor of the `Scanner` with a `FileChannel`, and then seek to position 0 and `reset` the `Scanner`, but I don't know if this would work, and it's easier just to make a new `Scanner`.

Alternatively, as suggested in the comments (although you state that this isn't possible in your case), you could read the contents into some data structure in memory first and then operate on that data.

---

That said, looking at your code, you could probably just combine `edgesSet` and `verticesSet` into one function, so you only need to read the file once, e.g.:

- Read the file one line at a time. For each line:

  - Store the whole line in the edge set as you do now
  - Split the line you just read into vertex indices and store them in the vertex set

And just do that for every line, to build both sets at once.

Answer (score 0):

I mean *after* you've read the file:

```
List<Integer> savedValues = null;
try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"))) {
    savedValues = s.tokens().
    map(String::trim).
    map(Integer::valueOf).
    toList();
}
```